# Email notification for when apps sell on google play?

Tags: android, google-play

By default I receive an email notification for when a user cancels the order and returns my app. Is there a way to change the notification settings so I receive an email when the app sells as well? I have looked the google play developer console and done lots of searching but cant find the option.

Comment: Would this really make sense?! There are apps that sell thousand times a day or more. Imagin when the seller receives an eMail for every sold copy!!!

Comment: Yah, not everyone sells a lot. What if my app was 50 bucks a pop and only sold a few times a week?